# Cloud Sync and NETBIOSNAME mapping issue

Tags: windows, netbios

I have an issue related to cloud sync and mechanism of mapping attributes. In details I have domain where the name is like  "`abc.domain.local`"  After run synchronization I discovered that when users execute command "whoami" receive `abc\<username>` instead of  `domain\<username>`. I think it is a huge bug , (be cause on background probably there is a function which triming string to first dot ) in cloudSync solution but lets focus on issue . I need advice how rollback or how to force change netbiosname on users account. I know there is an option to change NetBIOS name value in configuration from %netbiosdomain% to directed string but I am afraid that operation make bad consequence

---

Yes, i  am talking about Azure AD Cloud Sync

Comment: Are you talking about Azure AD Cloud Sync or some other kind of Cloud Sync?

Comment: yes, I am thinking about Azure AD Cloud Sync

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and its a HUGE issue because it corrupts the `LogonCache` on Intune-joined computers resulting in users not being able to sign in unless it's a local account.

The solution is to hard code the correct NetBIOS in attribute mappings in Cloud Sync. Cloud Sync by default assumes the NetBIOS is a user's domain name without the top-level domain part i.e. the "company" in "company.com".

Affected computers need the bad NetBIOS regkey deleted then domain users can sign in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IdentityStore\LogonCache\{GUID}\SubPkgs\{incorrect NetBIOS}
```

UPDATE: After more testing with Microsoft Support, it was determined hardcoding NetBIOS in Cloud Sync did not resolve this issue.